# "BadValue Unsupported projection option" error in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

MongoError: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue Unsupported projection option: $inc: { count: 1 }

```
var totalActiveUser = (req, res, next) => {
TotalUser.findOne({ default: "active"}, { $inc: { count: 1 }},
 function(err, result) {
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log(result);   
   res.send(result);
  });
```

modelSchema for this:

```
   activeCount: {
   type: Number,
   count: 0,
   default:"active"
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using $inc which is an update operation with findOne, It should be used with findOneandupdate. With findOne this second {} becomes projection.

Also, what is your motive with this query?

if you want to update then:

```
var totalActiveUser = (req, res, next) => {
TotalUser.findOneAndUpdate({ default: "active"}, { $inc: { count: 1}},
 function(err, result) {
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log(result);   
   res.send(result);
  });
```

**ADD multi: true for all updations**

To count the number of active users try this:

```
TotalUser.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $match: {
        default:"active"
      }
    },
    {
      $count: "active_users"
    }
  ]
)
```

or without aggregation:

```
TotalUser.find({"default" : "active"}).count()
```

Comment: Hye Shivani, thanks for replying..actually,I was trying to count the active users on my site.